# How to access properties in BeanFactoryPostProcessor with spring boot 1.5.x

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to get properties from application.yml in BeanFactoryPostProcessor with spring boot 1.5.x:

The application.yml:

```yaml
prong: 
  nfcloan:
    jackson:
      json-sub-types-package:
      - com.shuweicloud.starter.acc.dto.request
```

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prong.nfcloan.jackson")
public class JacksonProperties {

    private List<String> jsonSubTypesPackage;

    public List<String> getJsonSubTypesPackage() {
        return jsonSubTypesPackage;
    }

    public void setJsonSubTypesPackage(List<String> jsonSubTypesPackage) {
        this.jsonSubTypesPackage = jsonSubTypesPackage;
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class AccBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor{

    @Autowired
    private JacksonProperties jacksonProperties;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        List<String> packages = jacksonProperties.getJsonSubTypesPackage();
        // do something
    }

}
```

The main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JacksonProperties.class})
public class AccountingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

But the `packages` variable is null. How to solve it?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: You cannot. As `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instances are created very early in the proces.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution:

```java
@Component
public class AccBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        List<String> packages = environment.getProperty("prong.nfcloan.jackson.json-sub-types-package", List.class);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot internally uses Binder APIs to "map" the resolved properties into the `@ConfigurationProperties` beans.

Indeed, this resolution happens during the spring boot startup process **after** the BeanFactoryPostProcessors get created.

Now your solution will clearly work, because you kind of "bypass" this resolution.

However if you want to still have the Configuration as an instance of `JacksonProperties` (might be relevant if you have a lot of properties to resolve, or in general prefer to work more in a more spring-ish manner), you can use this binder API:

```
   // inside the "postProcessBeanFactory" method, using the injected environment
   BindResult<ExampleProperties> bindResult = Binder.get(environment)
                    .bind("prong.nfcloan.jackson", JacksonProperties.class);
   JacksonProperties properties = bindResult.get();
```

Comment: Thank's, but I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.x，I can't find the `Binder` API in Spring Boot 1.5.x.